# How can I make a Discord bot reply to new posts on a forum?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am using discord.py and I would like to create a bot that can monitor a forum and reply to new posts in real-time. Specifically, I want the bot to respond with a message like "Hello {author.mention}, please stay in this thread and do not make duplicates. Thanks!" when a user creates a new post.

I have looked into the Discord API, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I'm also not sure how to set up real-time monitoring for new posts.

Any suggestions or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer to the problem. It seems that there is a event in discord.py which is `on_thread_create` and it lets you do anything once a thread has been created. The code implementation is:

```
@client.event
async def on_thread_create(thread):
    # check if the thread is in the desired channel
    if thread.parent.name == "my-forum":
        # send a message to the thread
        reply = f"Hello {thread.owner.mention}, please stay in this thread(Don't ping people in <@968504682387492885>) and do not make duplicates. If no one responds to your thread within 1hr, ping `WSC Tech Supporter` Thanks!"
        await thread.send(reply)
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to check if a message is a thread

In discord.py, you can use `.type` on the return type of `message.channel` to get its type.

Example:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.type == "public_thread":
        await message.channel.send(message.author.mention)
        # mentions the author every time a message is sent in a public thread
```

### You probably don't want to send one for every message

So, you can save it locally. Save the channel ID in a JSON file and do another check.

### Resources

- [fetch_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_channel#discord.Client.fetch_channel)
- [message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_channel#message)
- [channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_channel#discord.Message.channel)